# Example for setting (multiple) parameters in Python LXML XSLT

Tags: python, xslt, lxml, parameters

Looked for the solution to this problem for a while since [the documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt) isn't really clear on it.

I ended up using the method below, and thought I'd share back.

Comment: The documentation says "The parameters are passed as keyword parameters to the transform call" which, assuming the documentation on keyword arguments https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments, seems clear. I agree, however, that the documentation shows no example of passing two or more parameters. On the other hand, your sample in the answer then should show both the XSLT as well as the Python code, if you want it to clearly show the use of two parameters.

Comment: updated question title to example, and also updated answer with xslt example

Answer (score 6):

Apparently you can [chain parameter arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) when applying the XSLT to the original xml tree. 
I found the most reliable way is to always use the *tree.XSLT.strparam()* method for wrapping the argument values. 
Not really needed I guess for simpler types like string or integers. But this method works regardless.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:param name="var1"/>
   <xsl:param name="var2"/>
   <!-- actual sheet omitted because example -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```python
from lxml import etree

var = "variable string"

original_tree = etree.parse("original.xml")
xslt_tree = etree.parse("transform.xsl")
xslt = etree.XSLT(xslt_tree)
lom_tree = xslt(original_tree, var1=etree.XSLT.strparam("str_example"), var2=etree.XSLT.strparam(var))

print(etree.tostring(lom_tree, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: In what way is using `strparam` a solution to the problem in your question, to set multiple parameters? Or if you think the other examples in the documentation are not reliable, in what way do they fail for you? If someone wants to pass in a number value, I don't see why using `strparam` would make that reliable, in that case using a number as done in the sample in the documentation seems the right way.

Comment: replaced the reliable part with example in title, and also added some explanation for using simple types

Comment: Do note, you can embed xslt as a python string and bind parameters to it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the concern about using strparam is only that when you don't read *carefully enough* the [xlst documentation of lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt), you don't realize that anything you pass as just a string is interpreted as a xpath !

```
  transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_tree)
  doc_root = etree.XML('<a><b>Text</b></a>')

  ### "5" is a numeric value, so it's sent as is
  result = transform(doc_root, a="5")

  ### "/a/b/text()" *and* "test" are both interpreted as a xpath !
  result = transform(doc_root, a="/a/b/text()")
  result = transform(doc_root, a="test")

  ### to actually send the string "test", you *must* quote it twice or use strparam
  result = transform(doc_root, a="'test'")
  result = transform(doc_root, a=etree.XSLT.strparam("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation you linked](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt) offers the use of dictionaries when passing in non-python-identifiers.  Passing in dictionaries also allows you to include numerous variables.  Using your XLS:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:param name="var1"/>
   <xsl:param name="var2"/>
   <!-- actual sheet omitted because example -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Modifying your code to include a dictionary and the use of eTree.strparam() functions, you can use the following to pass in multiple variables:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

argDict = {}
argDict["var1"] = ET.XSLT.strparam("variable 1 string")
argDict["var2"] = ET.XSLT.strparam("variable 2 string")

original_tree = ET.parse("original.xml")
xslt_tree = ET.parse("transform.xsl")
xslt = ET.XSLT(xslt_tree)
lom_tree = xslt(original_tree, **argDict)

print(ET.tostring(lom_tree, pretty_print=True))
```

EDIT: [updated documentation](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree._ElementTree.xslt)